# Download open file

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I want to download Word file with FTP (thanks to webClient object). It's working fine but not in this case :

Users of my company can open this Word files. So, when a user has opened a file the DownloadData command returns an exception :

> error 550 : File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

There is a way to download an opened file with FTP ? If not, what can i do ?

Thanks !

Comment: What type/brand of FTP server are you trying to hit?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how it's related to programming? The error is pretty descriptive .. without code it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost assuredly a poor architecture for whatever project you are working on. You probably want to separate the user editable document store from the downloadable document store. There are many solutions for keeping the two directories in sync when a change is made by a user (dropbox, mesh, or even custom scripts using robocopy and such).

Answer (score 1):

When an Office program opens a file for modification, it intentionally opens it exclusively. As a result, no FTP server is going to be able to open it, unless it uses the backup API. If it uses the backup API, it may well get some intermediate state, since Office may be in the middle of writing something at any time. So no sane person implements an FTP server to use the  backup API.